# How to access an application deployed in weblogic server from another machine within same network?

Tags: web-applications, weblogic

I have an **Application** deployed in  **Weblogic Server** and I am able to access it via my machine.
What shall i do in order to access the same url from another machine in Intranet(within same LAN)?

Comment: I suppose your server instance is only listening to the localhost. Update your server configuration and update the ListenAddress to listen to your IP address instead.